# Unix system programming: File open error

Tags: unix, file-io

I am trying to open a file which I created just before open command. But it hangs at `open()` command line. Do you have any idea?

```
if(mkfifo("test", S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IRWXO))
{
    printf("File creation error.\n");
    return 0;
}

// Hangs below
while (((test_fd = open("test", O_RDONLY)) == -1) && (errno == EINTR));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the manpage of mkfifo :

```
 Opening a FIFO for reading normally blocks until some other process opens  the  same  FIFO for  writing,  and vice versa.
 See fifo(7) for nonblocking handling of FIFO special files.
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I just changed the O_RDONLY with O_RDWR and it is working now.